# Mysqli Query is not returning any result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I seem to be having trouble getting mysqli to return a result from my query. My code is:

```
$db_conn = get_database(); //function returns a static mysqli object reference

if($result = $db_conn->query("SELECT city 
                                FROM state 
                               WHERE name='CA' ")) {
  $row = $result->fetch_object();
  $city= $row->city;
  $result->close();
} else {
  echo $db_conn->error;
}
```

When I echo the contents of the city variable, it contains nothing.

Comment: Does the query statement return results when executed within a mysqli client?

Comment: it does i have successfully exectued it from the cli. Also i have used the same mysqli else where in code and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check `get_database()` to make sure the proper database is selected
2. The column `state` in your where clause is the same as your table name, `state`. Change that to `name` instead if you can.